# Is there any way to set up HAProxy to wait an amount of time before marking a server `up`?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We're using HAProxy v1.3 to load balance between a bunch of Windows VMs in Amazon's EC2, and hare having some issues with instance stability. We've got our own monitoring in place, so we're aware of when an instance starts dropping requests or starts behaving even worse, but one of the problems is that it may sporadically start working for a brief period of time, so HAProxy thinks it's up, starts feeding it requests, only to have them eventually get close/timeout, which is becoming a big problem.

When it does this, the instance flaps between the two states with a period of less than two minutes, so I'm wondering if there's any way we can configure HAProxy to only add servers if they've been consistently up for a period of time (say, 5 minutes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `rise <count>`
>   The "rise" parameter
>   states that a server will be
>   considered as operational   after
>    consecutive successful health
>   checks. This value defaults to 2   if
>   unspecified. See also the "check",
>   "inter" and "fall" parameters.

[HAProxy Configuration](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt)